# I would like to calculate $\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{6}} \frac{2 \sin^2{x}+\sin{x}-1}{2 \sin^2{x}-3 \sin{x}+1}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

I want to calculate the following limit: $$\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{6}} \frac{2 \sin^2{x}+\sin{x}-1}{2 \sin^2{x}-3 \sin{x}+1}$$
or prove that it does not exist. Now I know the result is $-3$, but I am having trouble getting to it. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Since the numerator and denominator vanish when $x=\frac{\pi}{6}$ (i.e., when $\sin(x)=\frac{1}{2}$), try factoring out $\sin(x)-\frac{1}{2}$ from the numerator and denominator.  In other words, if you let $y=\sin(x)$, then this limit is $\lim_{y\rightarrow\frac{1}{2}}\frac{2y^2+y-1}{2y^2-3y+1}$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may just observe that, $\color{#3366cc}{\sin (\pi/6) =1/2}$ and that, as $x \to \pi/6$,
$$
\require{cancel}
\frac{2 \sin^2{x}+\sin{x}-1}{2 \sin^2{x}-3 \sin{x}+1}=\frac{\cancel{\color{#3366cc}{(2 \sin{x}-1)}}(\sin{x}+1)}{\cancel{\color{#3366cc}{(2 \sin{x}-1)}}(\sin{x}-1)}=\frac{\sin{x}+1}{\sin{x}-1} \color{#cc0066}{\longrightarrow} \frac{1/2+1}{1/2-1}=\color{#3366cc}{-3}
$$

---

Some details. One has
$$
\begin{align}
 2u^2+u-1 &=2\left(u^2+\frac{u}2-\frac12 \right) \\
 & =  2\left[\left(u +\frac14\right)^2-\frac1{16}-\frac12 \right] \\
 & =  2\left[\left(u +\frac14\right)^2-\frac9{16}\right] \\ 
 & =  2\left[\left(u +\frac14-\frac34\right)\left(u +\frac14+\frac34\right)\right] \\ 
 & =  2\left[\left(u -\frac12\right)\left(u +1\right)\right] \\ 
 & =  \left(2u -1\right)\left(u +1\right) 
\end{align}
$$ giving, with $u:=\sin x$,

> $$
> 2 \sin^2{x}+\sin{x}-1=\color{#3366cc}{(2 \sin{x}-1)}\left(\sin x +1\right).
> $$

Similarly,

> $$
> 2 \sin^2{x}-3\sin{x}+1=\color{#3366cc}{(2 \sin{x}-1)}\left(\sin x -1\right).
> $$

Comment: Could you please explain how you got this: $\frac{(2 \sin{x}-1)(\sin{x}+1)}{(2 \sin{x}-1)(\sin{x}-1)}$ ? I have been trying hard to figure it out, but I am lost.

Comment: Brilliant and beautiful result

Answer (score 2):

As this is in the form of $\frac{0}{0}$,so apply L Hospital rule
$\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{6}} \frac{2 \sin^2{x}+\sin{x}-1}{2 \sin^2{x}-3 \sin{x}+1}$
$=\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{6}} \frac{4 \sin x\cos x+\cos x}{4 \sin x\cos x-3 \cos x}=\frac{\sqrt3+\frac{\sqrt3}{2}}{\sqrt3-\frac{3\sqrt3}{2}}=-3$

Answer (score 1):

Notice, $$\lim_{x\to \pi/6}\frac{2\sin^2 x+\sin x-1}{2\sin^2 x-3\sin x+1}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to \pi/6}\frac{\sin x-(1-2\sin^2 x)}{2-3\sin x-(1-2\sin^2 x)}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to \pi/6}\frac{\sin x-\cos 2x}{2-3\sin x-\cos 2x}$$
Apply L'hospital's rule for $\frac00$ form 
$$=\lim_{x\to \pi/6}\frac{\cos x+2\sin 2x}{-3\cos x+2\sin2x}$$
$$=\frac{\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}+\sqrt 3}{-\frac{3\sqrt 3}{2}+\sqrt 3}=\color{red}{-3}$$